# How to check what route (interface) does a destination IP address belong to without sending anything?

Tags: linux, networking, routes

How to look up IP address in routing table (retrieve network interface index and MAC) without sending any packets there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `ip` command:

```
# ip route get to 74.125.228.197
74.125.228.197 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.100
```

And once you know the interface you can get its index and link/ether(MAC) address:

```
# ip addr show eth0 
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 100
link/ether 88:00:00:00:f2:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
inet6 fe80::3039:34ff:fe2c:f24c/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Can it be done with simple `ioctl` like SIOCADDRT (without calling external binary or using `AF_NETLINK`)?

Comment: I've never bothered, but you can see how `ip` does it by looking in its [source](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git/tree/ip/iproute.c)

Comment: @Joe I have a similar problem, please excuse my lack of knowledge, but I would like to know which interface should be used to join a multicast IPv6 group which is not local on the machine.

Comment: A similar (i.e. not exactly the same) problem deserves its own question - please do create one.